# BeautifulSoup findAll not returning values on webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to webscrape individual game pages on yahoo sports.

This is an example of the type of webpage i would like to scrape: https://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/atlanta-falcons-philadelphia-eagles-20180906021/?section=teamcomparison

Underneath the initial Box Score, you will see a tab titled "Team Comparison". What I am trying to obtain are the statistics that are underneath "Offensive/Defensive Team Ranks" for each team.

```
# The URL i would like to scrape.
url = 'https://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/atlanta-falcons-philadelphia-eagles- 
20180906021/?section=teamcomparison'

# Reading in the HTML code with BeautifulSoup
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
#page_soup

# Finding the segment of HTML code with my desired stats
stats = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "D(ib) Bxz(bb) W(100%)"})
print(stats)
### Result line -> In [743]: []
```

This is should be giving me the list of Offensive and Defensive ranks per team (e.g., Atlanta Passing Yards Per Game = 309.3 and Passing Yards Per Game Rank = 4), however it is only giving me "[]" and not returning any values. I believe this is because of the Javascript embedded in the webpage, however i am new to webscraping and not sure how to go about this.

Comment: If the content is loaded dynamically with JavaScript, BeautifulSoup is not suitable; you'll need to use something like Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is actually downloaded from the API with AJAX, so you don't need to scrape it, you can ask API yourself if you know how to compose the URL. For example for the page that you gave in your post the URL is: https://sports.yahoo.com/site/api/resource/sports.game.team_stat_leaders;id=nfl.g.20180906021

So you only need to know the `id` part of the url for every game. The JSON you will get in response is a little bit obscure but after a while it is possible to understand what is going on :).

Example code to get the data:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://sports.yahoo.com/site/api/resource/sports.game.team_stat_leaders;id=nfl.g.20180906021")
data = response.json()
```

Comment: Wow thank you. You were right, a little obscure at first, however i got the hang of it after understanding how the file is formatted.

Comment: How did you find the link to the API page? I am trying to gather more data.

Comment: I used developers tools in the browser. Hit F12 and go to the Network tab, then refresh (F5) the page you want to scrape. Look for xhr requests, you can use up and down arrows to navigate quickly. In the response body try to find (using ctrl+f in the response body tab) values you want to scrape, in case above I look fore '309.3'. It might seem as a tedious task but it should be quite quick actually.